# How can I pivot result of SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have this result in for my SQL query

[image]

and I want to convert it like this

[image]

Comment: Try to see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table   (this is first result using Google search with words: pivot mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use (a fake) aggregation function and group by

```
select type_revenue
  , max(case when location_name ='30juin' then amount else 0 end) 30Jui
  , max(case when location_name ='Bandal' then amount else 0 end) Bandal
from my_tbale 
group by type_revenue
```